# What are the advantages and disadvantages of dual wielding in 13th Age?

Tags: optimization, fighter, 13th-age

Our normal 4e encounters group is running a 13th Age playtest session, and I'm creating a Level 1 fighter character based on Adam Jensen from Deus Ex: Human Revolution. I'm skimming the rules and the classes and, beyond the one ranger class feat, I can't find anything in the playtest notes about penalties or bonuses from dual wielding weapons.

The Ranger feat:

> "Double Melee Attack (Ranger Attack) When fighting with two melee weapons, drop the damage die of each of your weapons by one notch (for example, 1d8 becomes 1d6). You can make a second attack if your first attack roll is a natural even roll.

I only played the play-test/beta before the book was published. Now that its out I am curious if there is anything more or if there is still only the ranger feat.

Comment: Now that the book has come out, I can answer based on the released rules. Would that be helpful?

Comment: @jadasc yes if you could write up an answer to this that'd be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Escalation V6 rules, page 197, under Two Weapon Fighting.

> You fight as normal, generally using the
>   weapon in your main hand to attack. If your
>   attack roll is a natural 2, you can reroll the attack
>   but must use the reroll. If it suits the story of
>   how your character fights, go ahead and use
>   your off-hand weapon for this rerolled attack,
>   but you don’t have to do that unless you want
>   to.

The Fighter has the Power "Two Weapon Pressure" as well. However, the Ranger is to go-to guy for dual wielding.

The advantage for two weapon fighting as a Fighter is that you have a 1 in 20 chance of re-rolling an attack, plus on a miss, you get a +2 attack against the same target next round (if you pick Two Weapon Pressure). The downside is you lose AC from not having a shield. (Two Weapon Pressure is a level 1 Power, and it triggers on any miss, so maybe it's good enough to compensate for a lack of shield)